# MySQL - Selecting last entry in second table when joining 2 tables

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have 2 tables transactions and trans_comments when I do an inner join it returns the very 1st entry, what I want to do is display the address and status form the transactions table and the last comment entered and date from the trans_comments table

here's what I got

```
SELECT t.address, t.status, c.time, c.comment
FROM transactions t
INNER JOIN trans_comments c ON c.transactionId = t.transactionId
WHERE STATUS LIKE  '%Listing%'
GROUP BY t.address DESC
```

what am I missing?

Here is the layout of the tables:

```
`transactions` (
  `transactionId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `listing_agent` varchar(65) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `notes` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `file_type` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `system` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`transactionId`)      
)ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=41 ;

`trans_comments` (
  `commId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `transactionId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comment` blob NOT NULL,
  `commentBy` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`commId`),
  KEY `transactionId` (`transactionId`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=101 ;
```

Thanks

Comment: you're being undone by mysqls 'helpfulness'. `group by` can't be used for what you're trying to use it for - the values it selects for fields not in the `group by` clause, or not used in an aggregate function are indeterminate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.address, t.status, c.time, c.comment
FROM transactions t
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT c1.*
   FROM trans_comments c1
   LEFT JOIN trans_comments c2
   ON c1.transactionId = c2.transactionId 
     AND c1.`time` < c2.`time` 
   WHERE c2.commId IS NULL
  ) c 
ON c.transactionId = t.transactionId
WHERE STATUS LIKE  '%Listing%'
```